# Temporary URLs that expire after download

Tags: java, php, download

I'd like to create a launcher for a Java game I'm developing that will require the user to log in before the game itself can be downloaded. My idea was to have the launcher send the credentials to my webserver, and the webserver would output the location of a temporary file given the credentials were correct. However, this would be a bit tricky/inefficient, given:

1. The server would need to copy the game file every time someone updates, and
2. The webserver wouldn't know when the file was finished downloading.

Perhaps the launcher could send a request to a separate script to delete a file of the given temporary name? The problem with that is that the launcher could easily be decompiled and modified to not send the request, defeating the purpose of creating a new file.

Any suggestions as to this idea and its issues?

Comment: You might add a "validation code" to the URL - so the basic request is the same, but there's a `?valKey=123345456567ertdfgertdfg` after the URL. Your php decodes that it is a valid key, serves up the requested file, then marks the key as no longer valid.

Comment: Out of curiosity - why not download right away when the credentials are valid? Why the new URL?

Comment: @Niels The user would be able to download the file from a static URL, defeating the purpose of validation.

Comment: And who cares whether the URL is static or dynamic, as long as it downloads the file? I think you're severely overcomplicating the problem.

Comment: But, the user should only be able to download the file if they have the proper credentials.

Comment: @mproncace exactly, once you verify their credentials then start the download. Why bother redirecting and limiting the user to downloading the file only once? Just do a POST request to the static download URL with the credentials, verify the account and start the download.

Comment: @Niels Would that work? I'm not totally clear as to how Java handles downloads from redirects.

Comment: The same as any other client - correctly. But still, why redirect and not just download immediately? You're really overcomplicating it.

Comment: @Niels In this case, the redirect would act as a sort of middle-man, serving the purpose of validating credentials. Additionally, the file wouldn't be hosted in the document root; otherwise it could easily be downloaded with another client without validation.

Comment: Like we are all trying to say - you can validate, and start a download, from a file outside the document root, *all in the same HTTP request*. There's no obvious valid reason to use multiple requests, or redirects, for this simple problem. All you need to do is `if(hasValidCredentials) { header("Content-type: application/octet-stream"); readfile('local/path/to/file'); die; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a database, like this:

urlgenerator.php

```
 <?php

 // generate code
 $code = uniqid();

 // save code to database
 db_save($code);

 // write link
 echo '<a href="download.php?code=' . $code . '">Download</a>';
```

download.php

```
<?php

// get code from url
$single_use_code = $_GET['code'];

// check if the code is in the db
if(db_get_code($single_use_code)) {
   // remove code from database as it is single use only
   db_remove($single_use_code);
   // start download
   start_download();
} else {
   // the code is not valid
   die('BAD code');
}
```

Comment: +1 for turning into understandable code what the rest of us were just commenting about!

Comment: Mmm, delicious! This is very understandable for both noobs **and experts!** Even though I am experienced, I didn't really understand a lot of the code that others provided, but **you**.. You provided very understandable code, that even someone who **hasn't coded a single line in their life will understand!** I applaud you! +1!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
// Define a random key
$key = 'kgjiowtjiohgjiut09ig90im09yig90mi903i490ti209tgwgt';  
$secondsValid = 300;

if($_GET['action'] == 'download')
{
  $time = $_GET['time'];
  if(time() - $time > $secondsValid)
    die('Code has expired, please try again');
  if($_GET['validation'] != md5($time.$key))
    die('Invalid validation code');
  DownloadFile();
  die;
}
elseif(CredentialsAreCorrect())
{
  $time = time();
  header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'?action=download&time='.$time.'&validation='.md5($time.$key));
  die;
}
else
  die('Invalid credentials');
```

This is an easy way to give a validated user a timebombed URL (valid for 5 minutes in this case) without any nasty copying/symlinking/whatever involved, no databases, just using basic facilities that cannot be hacked as long as the key is secure. Just make sure your key has enough entropy (40+ random keypresses should do it) so no rainbow table or brute force attack is feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Simple workaround: on a unix system, you can remove a file while it's in use without affecting currently-open file handles on that file. so

1. user requests download
2. script makes a symlink in the documentroot somewhere that points at wherever the file is really stored (somewhere outside of the document root)
3. URL to the symlink is send out as a parameter to the user.
4. User clicks on the donwload link, e.g. `http://example.com?get=path/of/symlink`
5. The download script fopen()'s the symlink and starts dishing out the file's contents
6. script **REMOVES** the symlink after it's been fopen()'d

Now the symlink is gone and can't be reused anymore, but the download script will still be sending data to the user because it opened the symlink/file before it was removed.

Comment: "on a unix system" My webserver runs on Windows; would this still work?