# How to stop spam downloads

Tags: wordpress, file, amazon-s3, download, spam-prevention

I am thinking of using Amazon s3 or even google drive for my website that has a few downloadable files.  Problem is I don't really see how to stop spam in this case.  Amazon s3 looks like a great way for spammers to give you a $100,000 bill.  There is no captcha option and most have to be off site.  Are there any hosts that can stop this (have captcha) or is this just a case of wait for a person to spam download and you are helpless to stop.

I can not find a lot on this issue to my surprise.

Comment: how about a simple form that allow user to input their email address and you can send your download link directly to that specific email address?

Comment: @Khánh That's actually not a bad idea,  I guess though they could in theory keep spamming with new e-mails but you could add captcha.  Though once they recieve emailed download link I suppose they could just spam download then xD

Comment: You can use this suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/a/16134485/3516008 within `Content-Disposition` header https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628260/downloading-a-file-with-a-different-name-to-the-stored-name